# Button event increases count; How to stop count at given value?

Tags: racket

Given; button event triggers (accelerate); (accelerate) increases current-speed by 10. How can I get the current-speed value to stop at 65?
Inversely, button event triggers (brake); (brake) decreases current-speed by 7. How can I get current-speed to stop at 0?

```
 (define/public (accelerate)
      (cond
        ((> current-speed 65) = 65 current-speed)
        (else (set! current-speed (+ current-speed 10)))))     
     
    (define/public (brake)
      (cond
        ((< current-speed 0) = 0 current-speed)
        (else (set! current-speed (- current-speed 7)))))
```

As it runs now, (accelerate) will increase to 70 then stop.
(brake) will decrease to any negative value to -7.
I'm not committed to a conditional, I'm just not sure how else to implement.

Comment: What you actually want to check is if ((current-speed + 10) > 65) and ((current-speed - 7) < 0). Update the if conditions and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something in one case, and nothing in the opposite case, use `when`.
To limit the value, use `min` and `max`.

```
(define/public (accelerate)
    (when (< current-speed 65)
        (set! current-speed (min 65  (+ current-speed 10)))))
     
(define/public (brake)
    (when (> current-speed 0)
        (set! current-speed (max 0 (- current-speed 7)))))
```